# Count number of listings instead number of posts wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, listings

I'm using Profile Builder for display all users page. Like this picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqFj1.png)

Users of Theme installed do not crete Posts but Listing.
So, instead the posts number in the label of the picture I need listings number.

Plugin have this code for display the posts number:

```
function wppb_userlisting_show_number_of_posts( $value, $name, $children, $extra_info ){
    $userID = wppb_get_query_var( 'username' );

    $user_id = ( !empty( $extra_info['user_id'] ) ? $extra_info['user_id'] : '' );
    $user_info = ( empty( $userID ) ? get_userdata( $user_id ) : get_userdata( $userID ) );

    $allPosts = get_posts( array( 'author'=> $user_info->ID, 'numberposts'=> -1 ) );
    $number_of_posts = count( $allPosts );

    return apply_filters('wppb_userlisting_extra_meta_number_of_posts', '<a href="'.get_author_posts_url($user_info->ID).'" id="postNumberLink" class="postNumberLink">'.$number_of_posts.'</a>', $user_info, $number_of_posts);
}
add_filter( 'mustache_variable_number_of_posts', 'wppb_userlisting_show_number_of_posts', 10, 4 );
```

And in my Theme I can use this code for display the listings number:

```
$listng_data = $CORE->USER("count_user_listings", $userdata->ID);
$num =  $listng_data['total'];
<?php echo $num; ?>
```

Thanks in advance for any help

I try a lot of combination but this variable is not accepted $CORE->USER("count_user_listings", $userdata->ID);
The php file of the plugin is made only of "functions"